# Remove last comma from foreach array result

Tags: php, foreach

I have this small function that let's me update any table and any values that I submit via a form. This is for personal use and no security is needed. But I need to remove the last comma from the script. First, here is the code:

```
public function updateForm($table, $formValues, $formID)
{
    foreach ($formValues as $key => $val)
    {
        $form = "$key = '$val', ";
        $this->mysqli->query("UPDATE `$table` SET $form WHERE id = '$formID'");
    }
}
```

If I submit 3 fields called `field1`, `field2`, and `field3` which contain the values `test1`, `test2` and `test3`, the `$form` will look like this:

> field1 = 'test1', field2 = 'test2', field3 = 'test3',

But that last comma needs to be gone. How would I accomplish this? I have tried everything I can think of, including `rtrim($form,',');` - But this also does not remove the last comma from the populated values.

Any shove into the right direction would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Build an array of `key = 'val'` strings. Use [`implode`](http://php.net/implode). Problem solved.

Comment: What about rtrim($form,', ')? note the space.

Comment: Thoronwen, that removes all comma's :) 

Dark Absol, sounds good, will try that thanks :D

Comment: Dark Absol, worked like a charm, thanks again :)

Comment: All of those approaches are slower than looping because they loop as well and you have the function call overhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach that doesn't require any kind of counting.

```
<?php

$string = null;
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  $string && ($string .= ", ");
  $string .= "{$key} = '{$value}'";
}
```

This always works and is ultra fast.

Answer (score 2):

First bring `$this->mysqli->query("UPDATE`$table`SET $form WHERE id = '$formID'");` outside of `foreach` loop.

Now, you can check last index if array while traversing it in a foreach loop.

```
public function updateForm($table, $formValues, $formID)
{
    foreach ($formValues as $key => $val)
    {
        $last_key = key( array_slice( $array, -1, 1, TRUE ) ); // Checks for array last index
        if ('key' == $last_key) {
            $form = "$key = '$val', ";      
        }
        else
            $form = "$key = '$val' ";
    }

    $this->mysqli->query("UPDATE `$table` SET $form WHERE id = '$formID'");
}
```

This will provide you output like this

```
field1 = 'test1', field2 = 'test2', field3 = 'test3'
```

You can also use `end()` to get last index but, `array_slice()` is quiet faster that `end()`

**To check last index using end()**

```
end(array_keys($myarr))
```